# PHP socket confusion

Tags: php, sockets

I am trying to understand PHP socket use for a specific scenario that I have previously used Perl to solve but would like to be able to complete the same process with PHP instead as part of a PHP project.

The equipment that I am connecting to will send out data on a specific port at any time and not to any specific address but it accepts 5 connections at any one time. That being the case, I need the PHP script to remain connected to the port while it accepts any data and displays this (for now)

I have got this code so far and it works to the point that I can get the connection and I can display a single data stream but once that stream end the connection drops:

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("config.ini");
$host=$ini_array[pbx];
$port=$ini_array[port];

echo nl2br("Connected to the $host on port $port\n");

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n"); 
$result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
echo $result.PHP_EOL;
```

The Perl solution that works for me includes a while loop but I can't figure out how to do this same thing in PHP:

```
my $cfg = new Config::Simple();
$cfg->read('config.ini');
my $host = $cfg->param("pbx");
my $port = $cfg->param("port");
print "Connecting to the PBX $host on port $port\n";
my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET(PeerAddr => $host, PeerPort => $port,Proto => "tcp",)
or die "Cannot connect at address: $host port: $port: $!";

while (<$sock>) {
s/^\0+//; # Remove leading null characters
print $_;
chomp ($_);
#$_ =~ s/^[^ ]+//;
if ($_ =~m"/") {
&TXTout;
}
```

Any suggestions would be welcomed!

Comment: Is this a web page or a CLI app no the server? If it is the former, although not impossible, it is much harder to do.

Comment: Hi Chris, this is a webpage but I would be interested in the CLI result as well if you have one?

Comment: For a webpage you are going to run into problems because of the client/server paradigm. The server specifically "wants to be done" as soon as possible, that's just the way of the web. And the server is also almost never PHP, but something else like Apache, Nginx etc. You can run PHP on the CLI pretty easily, just `php file.php` for simple testing or you can turn it into a shell script. I'd have the CLI do the listening and report to something, a text file or database, and have a web GUI that reads that.

Comment: Ok, that is pretty much exactly what I have happening with the perl scripts which reads the data and updates a sql database with the info. The reason I am looking at changing this is to try to give the users a more "realtime" view of the data so that they can see that the connection is alive. I understand the limitations better now as you have pointed them out. Maybe I can use something like iframe to display the console instead?

Comment: It really depends on how real-time you want to get. AJAX/XHR is a really common way to poll the server at periodic intervals and is the simplest, but it isn't going to be truly real time. But if people can wait 5 or 10 seconds, I would go with that. On the other side of the spectrum, I just built an application with [Pusher](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php) which is free for small amounts of data and uses either web sockets or server-sent events (I can't remember the details).

Comment: Ok great, looks like I have some more reading to do tonight, thanks Chris! :)